# Error loading MySQLdb module with Django on OS X

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I have a very strange situation that I can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm working on a Django project and I:

**Installed MySQL on OS X**

**Added the DATABASES values:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

But then Django/Mezzanine tells me that there's an error loading **MySQLdb** module.

**So I Googled for some tips around this and tried these methods:**

```
pip install mysql-python
```

- Reinstalled pip
- Downloaded ez_setup.py and installed

Now I'm stuck. The same error shows up and it feels like there's a problem with the MySQL connector/adapter to not be able to load this.

What should I try next?

**Edited with traceback:**

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:238: RemovedInDjango19Warning: In Django 1.9 the TEST_COLLATION connection setting will be moved to a COLLATION entry in the TEST setting
  self.prepare_test_settings(alias)

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1064bc5f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 154, in inner_run
    super(Command, self).inner_run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:238: RemovedInDjango19Warning: In Django 1.9 the TEST_COLLATION connection setting will be moved to a COLLATION entry in the TEST setting
  self.prepare_test_settings(alias)

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10de74500>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 154, in inner_run
    super(Command, self).inner_run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 107, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 252, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

**When running the pip command:**

```
The directory '/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The directory '/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 110kB 495kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-LaB_Nv/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-LaB_Nv/mysql-python
```

Comment: can you provide the full traceback of the error?

Comment: And exactly what happened when you ran the pip command? Are you doing that in the same virtualenv as your project?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Edited with the output now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the same when you are trying to install psycopg2 package for  postgres. To solve this problem, you have to add to the **PATH** your mysql bin directory.

Follow this steps :
1. Download **DMG Archive** and install latest official version of Mysql Community server : [mysql-5.7.9](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)
2. Add mysql bin directory to the PATH. To do that, add to your `~/.bash_profile` file this

```bash
# add mysql bin directory
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin/:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

3. Restart your computer
4. Run : `pip install mysql-python`

and it should output : `Successfully installed mysql-python-1.2.5`

Comment: Thank you so freakin much! This was a good and working answer!

Comment: your welcome :) If later, you are working with postgres, do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac User

mysql-connector-c have some issues So,

open the /usr/local/bin/mysql_config script to modify it:

```
Libs = "-L$pkglibdir"
Libs = "$libs -l"
```

change into:

```
Libs = "-L$pkglibdir"
Libs = "$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

Then install Python-Mysql,

```
pip install MySQL-python
```